# Visiting Falkland Islands with UK Tourist visa

Tags: serbian-citizens, falkland-islands

Hi my girlfriend is from Serbia, she just got a UK visitors permit for 6 months, can she also fly to  Falkland Islands with that  visa ? We couldn't find any information if UK tourist visa is also valid for Falkland Islands ( or generelly for all UK oversea territories ) . As far as I know it's not enough for Gibraltar but no idea about other oversea territories

Comment: According to https://www.falklands.gov.fk/our-home/visit-us/ she will need a visa. Other visa policies are here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policies_of_British_Overseas_Territories

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serbia is not on the list of visa-exempt countries for entry to the Falkland Islands https://www.falklands.gov.fk/our-home/visit-us/

The British Overseas Territories (BOTs) maintain their own rules regarding immigration requirements.  A BOT visa policy list is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policies_of_British_Overseas_Territories